# Ошибка в chrome связанная с websockets и ssl

Tags: websocket

Хром пишет в консоли ошибку при попытке соединения с вебсокет сервером - "failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH" .
Подключение к серверу реализовано по ssl (wss) . Что требует хром?
Код сервера:

```
// require
var http = require("https");

// https

var serverWss = http.createServer().listen(1001);

// websocketServer

var ws = require("ws");

var newWs = new ws.Server({
    server:serverWss,
});

newWs.on("connection", function (ws){

    // какой-то код 
});
```

Код клиента:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://domen.ru:1001');
```

Comment: в гугле таки забанили. https://rusadmin.biz/oshibki/err_ssl_version_or_cipher_mismatch-chto-za-oshibka-i-kak-ispravit/

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH&rlz=1C1SQJL_ruUA791UA791&oq=ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8